# Sanitizing script in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to try to sanitize script using $sce in AngularJS.

//Controller

```
 angular.module('App')
 .controller('SketchCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $sce , http) {
    $scope.init = function () {
        var sketchId = $location.path().split("/:").pop();
        http.getSketch(sketchId);
    }
    $scope.sanitize = function (script) {
        if(script){
            return $sce.trustAsJs(script);
        }
    }
 });
```

// View

```
<script ng-bind="sanitize('{Here is a script I want to sanitize}}')"></script>
```

But I got an error like this.

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

I know how to sanitize html but do you have any idea to sanitize script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you mentioned normally occurs when you create a loop of changes over a property. For example, like when you watch for changes on a certain property and then change the value of that property on the listener. You shouldn't change objects/models during the render or otherwise it will force a new render.

Answer (score 0):

To add to existing answers,

Simplified, `$sce.trustAsJs` notifies AngularJS's `$rootScope` that something may have changed, which most likely causes `ng-bind` to reevaluate the expression, the expression is calling `sanitize` and calls `$sce.trustAsJs` causing this to happen over and over until a limit is reached where it stops, because something seems to be going wrong.

Generally, just don't put function calls in html bindings unless they do really simple things. The way you can avoid what you're running into is to `ng-bind` a variable that you update only outside of the scope digest chain.

What you could for example do here is add [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit), which we know only runs once, to set a variable, and then make `ng-bind` reference it;

```
<script ng-init="script = sanitize('{Here is a script I want to sanitize}}')"
        ng-bind="script"></script>
```

You can also set `script` in the above example from a controller, just make sure you only call `sanitize` whenever the `script` changes or is initialized.

Also if you're trusting arbitrary JS that you want to run you, might as well keep it simple and use `eval`.